# UnderscoreJS group by numerical intervals for histogram

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Is there a way to group a list of numbers into numerical intervals with underscore?

```
// Input:
var arr = [0,1,2,8];
var interval = 3;

// Output:
// There are 3 numbers from 0 to <3
// There are 0 numbers from 3 to <6
// There is 1 number from 6 to <9 
// Returns [3, 0, 1]
```

I notice some solutions don't test larger values. Try a second test case:

```
var arr = [110,113,116,119];
```

Comment: is the data sorted?

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript, you could just divide the number by the interval and use the integer part for grouping.

With an array and missing intervals.

```js
function getHistogram(array, interval) {
    var bin,
        result = [];

    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var key = Math.floor(a / interval);
        if (!bin) {
            bin = [key, key];
            result[0] = 0;
        }
        while (key < bin[0]) {
            --bin[0];
            result.unshift(0);
        }
        while (key > bin[1]) {
            ++bin[1];
            result.push(0);
        }
        ++result[key - bin[0]];
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(getHistogram([0, 1, 2, 8], 3));
console.log(getHistogram([110, 113, 116, 119], 3));
console.log(getHistogram([15, 10, 26], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With an object and missing intervals.

```js
function getHistogram(array, interval) {
    var bin,
        result = {};

    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var key = Math.floor(a / interval);
        if (!bin) {
            bin = [key, key];
            result[key] = 0;
        }
        while (key < bin[0]) {
            result[--bin[0]] = 0;
        }
        while (key > bin[1]) {
            result[++bin[1]] = 0;
        }
        ++result[key];
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(getHistogram([0, 1, 2, 8], 3));
console.log(getHistogram([110, 113, 116, 119], 3));
console.log(getHistogram([15, 10, 26], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your code yields 0:3 and 6:1, but I do need a 3:0 as well. I think you're on the right track.

Comment: @JackWade, now in an array with default zeros.

Comment: This breaks down for larger values. var arr = [
        110,
        113,
        116,
        119
        ],
    interval = 3,

Comment: is the data sorted? do you need only the interval filled with missing zeroes?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of this solution is to generate a range of the histogram's X values, then iterate through the array while placing values less than each X in counts.

```js
var getIntervalCounts = function (arr){
  // Sort backwards to iterate through in reverse later
  arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return b - a;
  });

  var interval = 3;

  // Get values for range of histogram's x axis
  var greatestVal = arr[0];
  var leastVal = arr[arr.length-1];
  var x = _.range(leastVal + interval, greatestVal + interval + 1, interval);
  
  // Get value counts for histogram's y axis
  var y = _(x).map(function(num){
    var count = 0;

    // Remove elements from end of array while we iterate through
    // to avoid duplicate lookups
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      // Put everything less than the histogram x in that x value
      if (arr[i] < num) {
        count++;
        arr.pop();
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    return count;
  });
  
  // console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
}

getIntervalCounts([0,1,2,8]);
getIntervalCounts([110,111,112,118]);
getIntervalCounts([110,111,112,118,119]);
getIntervalCounts([110,111,112,118,119,120]);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the only correct solution so far. I was hoping for a more elegant _.chain style solution.

Comment: Right... I'm sure there's a way that's a bit more mathematical that could just plow through an unsorted array in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach using plain JS. I've added some more numbers to your example to test it better.

I use a new array to store the number of occurrences in each interval. The first position would represent the number of elements < interval, the second < 2*interval... and so on so forth.

I keep a reference to the last valid index so that I can fill empty cells with zeroes.

**UPDATE:** A minor fix to avoid having the first number as `undefined` when there's no value in range 0 <= x <= 3

```js
// Input:
var arr = [ 110, 113, 116, 119 ],
  interval = 3,
  res = [],
  lastIdx = -1;

arr.forEach(function(el) {
  var intPart = Math.floor(el / interval),
    index = el && intPart * interval === el ? intPart - 1 : intPart;

  res[index] = (res[index] || 0) + 1;
  res.fill(0, lastIdx + 1, index);
  lastIdx = index;
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE 2:** A version using underscore. It uses countBy to get the intervals and avoids using Array.prototype.fill because it's a ES6 feature.

```js
function getZeroFilledArr(len) {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(len)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
}

function getIntervalLentgh(intervals) {
  return Number(_.max(intervals)) + 1;
}

var arr = [110, 113, 116, 119],
  interval = 3,
  intervals = _.countBy(arr, function(el) {
    var intPart = Math.floor(el / interval);
    return el && intPart * interval === el ? intPart - 1 : intPart;
  }),
  zeroFilledArr = getZeroFilledArr(getIntervalLentgh(_.keys(intervals)));


console.log(_.reduce(intervals, function(memo, value, key) {
  memo[key] = value;
  return memo;
}, zeroFilledArr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: your not using underscore as requested

Comment: Try var arr = [
        110,
        113,
        116,
        119
        ];

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the most elegant way to doit

```js
_.mixin({
            step: function(ar, s) {
                var dummy = _.times(Math.ceil(_.max(ar)/s), function(){ return 0; });
                _.each(ar, function(x) {
                  dummy[Math.floor(x/s)]++; 
                });          
                return dummy;
            }
          });
        
        
          var arr = [0,1,2,4,6,7,8,9,22];
          var res1 =   _.step(arr, 3);                                
          console.log("RESULT1 ", res1.length, res1);

          var arr2 = [ 110, 113, 116, 119 ];
          var res2 = _.step(arr2, 3);
          console.log("RESULT2 ", res2.length, res2 );
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

The previous solutions do not consider the max value of the array so do not create the right size of the result array.

Using _.mixin gives you the ability to define a new function for underscore that can apply to array. So i created a _.step function that takes the array and the step.

Comment: This breaks for var arr = [
        110,
        113,
        116,
        119
        ];

Comment: Why you say itbreaks? It gives you back an array of 40, 36 have 0 and the last four have 1.

Comment: made a correction for a minor bug in the mixin referin to arr instead of ar